# How can I import a txt file with date and time columns into R using read_table without losing the format?

Tags: r, import, tidyverse

I have a txt file containing date and time in the first two columns but header has only date. and then there are other numeric columns.

```
DATE ID NB A_DATE ID IOD
2022-09-02 00:00:00 42274 5 2021-12-22 23:00:00 120 1
2022-09-09 00:00:00 42274 15 2023-12-22 23:00:00 120 1
2023-09-05 00:00:00 42274 18 2023-12-24 23:00:00 120 2
```

I can not import it into R. when I use read_table the whole data is imported as one character. How can I import this data into R keeping the format intact?

I tried to convert the txt file to csv using excel and had to remove the time column to do that. But I do not want to remove the time column.

Comment: It sounds like the file is not delimited - just rows of text with no markers between columns (commas, semicolons etc) - is that right?  If so, you may be better off reading it in as is and then splitting the lines up to make your table.

Comment: just to check, are you sure the spaces between columns are spaces not tabs?  It may be worth trying to read it as tab delimited just to see if it helps, since that's quick and easy.

Answer (score 0):

you could use `read_fwf`:

```
txt <- "DATE ID NB A_DATE ID IOD
2022-09-02 00:00:00 42274 5  2021-12-22 23:00:00 120 1
2022-09-09 00:00:00 42274 15 2023-12-22 23:00:00 120 1
2023-09-05 00:00:00 42274 18 2023-12-24 23:00:00 120 2"


readr::read_fwf(txt, readr::fwf_cols(DATE = 19, ID = 6, NB = 3, 
                                     A_DATE = 20, ID2 = 4, IOD = 2)) |> 
  dplyr::slice(-1)
```

**Output**:

```
  # A tibble: 3 × 6
  DATE                ID       NB A_DATE                ID2   IOD
  <chr>               <chr> <dbl> <dttm>              <dbl> <dbl>
1 2022-09-02 00:00:00 42274     5 2021-12-22 23:00:00   120     1
2 2022-09-09 00:00:00 42274    15 2023-12-22 23:00:00   120     1
3 2023-09-05 00:00:00 42274    18 2023-12-24 23:00:00   120     2
```

Comment: Note, your data is differently formatted to OPs - in line 1 you have a double space after the `5` in the `NB` column.  Without that, fixed widths won't work correctly, right?

Answer (score 0):

```
library(dplyr)
library(tidyr)
library(stringr)

#import your data with readlines()
lines_rec <- readlines("yourfile.txt")

#assuming the results of read_lines is something like:
lines_rec <- c("DATE ID NB A_DATE ID IOD",
"2022-09-02 00:00:00 42274 5 2021-12-22 23:00:00 120 1",
"2022-09-09 00:00:00 42274 15 2023-12-22 23:00:00 120 1",
"2023-09-05 00:00:00 42274 18 2023-12-24 23:00:00 120 2")

lines_tib <- 
  tibble(lines = lines_rec) # I prefer using tibble format

# create matching pattern
# named regexes will become new columns, unnamed will be required but dropped
# note we can't have repeated column names hence I used "ID2"
split_reg <- c(DATE = "\\d{4}-\\d{2}-\\d{2} \\d{2}:\\d{2}:\\d{2}"," ",
               ID = ".+", " ", 
               NB = ".+", " ",
               A_DATE = "\\d{4}-\\d{2}-\\d{2} \\d{2}:\\d{2}:\\d{2}"," ",
               ID2 = ".+", " ",
               IOD = ".+")

lines_tib <- lines_tib[-1,] # drop col names
lines_tib %>% 
  separate_wider_regex(
    cols = everything(),
    patterns = split_reg) %>%
  mutate(
    DATE = as.POSIXct(DATE),
    A_DATE = as.POSIXct(A_DATE)
  )
```

Output is:

```
# A tibble: 3 × 6
  DATE                ID    NB    A_DATE              ID2   IOD  
  <dttm>              <chr> <chr> <dttm>              <chr> <chr>
1 2022-09-02 00:00:00 42274 5     2021-12-22 23:00:00 120   1    
2 2022-09-09 00:00:00 42274 15    2023-12-22 23:00:00 120   1    
3 2023-09-05 00:00:00 42274 18    2023-12-24 23:00:00 120   2
```

Obviously you may wish to define types for the other columns other than `<chr>`, I have only bothered specifying the datetime ones.

Hope this is helpful.